# :root css - how can we stop it from being disabled in chrome devops?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, root

```
:root {
    --principalColor: #b3cbda;
    --secondaryColor: #d4916a;
    --nav: #fff;
    --hover: #ead5f2;
    --backgroundColor: #fff;
    --defaut-font: 'Merriweather' --événementiel-font: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    }
```

How can I stop anyone from disabling the :root selectors in Chrome devOps?

Comment: a Gold rule in the Computer World: avoid using `è` or `é` when naming things. You are probably a French person but don't write using French in codes. One day, you will thank me for this advice.

Comment: You can't prevent a user changing CSS rules in any browser's F12 Developer Tools.

Comment: In this case if the :root css is disabled can the colors and all other css elements still be maintained? Is there a way?

Comment: Temani Afif, yes,I know,it was my keyboard that made the change when I pasted the code.

Comment: Given you can't stop a user changing CSS through their browser dev tools, could you describe more what the problem actually is - why is the user altering CSS a worry?

Comment: I'm about to finish a project I created for dev classes and apparently the evaluator mentioned this as problematic but I'm not sure how to stop others from disabling the css :root elements.